# Communicate with subprocess without waiting for the subprocess to terminate on windows

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, readline

I have a simple echoprocess.py:

```
import sys

while True:
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    sys.stdout.write("Here is the data: " + str(data))
```

And a parentprocess.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["C:/python27/python.exe", "echoprocess.py"],
             stdin = PIPE,
             sdtout = PIPE)

proc.stdin.write("hello")
print proc.stdout.read()
```

This just hangs until echoprocess.py is terminated. I want to communicate with this subprocess multiple times without having to restart it again. Is this kind of interprocess communication possible with the Python subprocess module on Windows?

Comment: Just added a note regarding output buffering to my answer. Not sure about Windows, but on Linux the one in `echoprocess.py` is necessary, although the one in `parentprocess.py` isn't. It's usually safest to always include them for maximum portability.

Comment: It might also be worth looking at the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, which provides an abstraction layer for this sort of inter-process communication.

Comment: That is what I did originally, but I had some initial problems with it on Windows. The Windows requirement to put all all of the code in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block seemed to require too much work around of what I already have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is with the line...

```
print proc.stdout.read()
```

The `read()` method when used with no parameters will read all data until EOF, which will not occur until the subprocess terminates.

You'll probably be okay with line-by-line reading, so you can use...

```
proc.stdin.write("hello\n")
print proc.stdout.readline()
```

...otherwise you'll have to work out some others means of delimiting 'messages'.

You'll have to make a similar change to `echoprocess.py`, i.e. change...

```
data = sys.stdin.read()
```

...to...

```
data = sys.stdin.readline()
```

You may also have issues with output buffering, so it may be necessary to `flush()` the buffer after doing a write.

---

Putting all this together, if you change `echoprocess.py` to...

```
import sys

while True:
    data = sys.stdin.readline()
    sys.stdout.write("Here is the data: " + str(data))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

...and `parentprocess.py` to...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["C:/python27/python.exe", "echoprocess.py"],
             stdin = PIPE,
             stdout = PIPE)

proc.stdin.write("hello\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
print proc.stdout.readline()
```

...it should work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Works as expected. What exactly does flush do?

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson Well, for efficiency, processes will usually have an internal buffer and calls to `write()` will actually be stored in the buffer until it reaches a certain size, at which point it'll be passed on to the piped process. Calling `flush()` forces that to happen immediately, rather than waiting for the buffer to be filled. There's probably a better description on the web somewhere.

Comment: Maybe it used to work back in the day, but nowadays (python 3.11) it simply doesn't work. There are tons of errors displaying, like `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` or `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1250'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` during flush. I hope someone can update this answer :(