# Python can not capture full adb logs

Tags: android, python, logging, adb

What I want to achieve -
running adb log (logs are running),
doing some activity on android,
stop/end log capture (ctrl+c),
post processing of logs.

Only issue which i face -
can not capture full logcat log in file

```
import sys 
import subprocess
import time
import ctypes

# start

print "test start"
time.sleep(5)

# log capturing start, log does not stop it will keep on running
proc = subprocess.Popen("adb logcat -v time",stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
time.sleep(3) # just so it runs for a while


print "calc start"
time.sleep(5)
#START test************************************

Some code for testing



#CTRL C*************************************************

try:
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0, 0)
    proc.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "ignoring ctrlc"
print "still running"


#********************adb log saving******************

text = proc.stdout.read()

f = open('C:\Python27\out_logs_dd\log.txt', 'w')

f.write(text)

with open('C:\Python27\out_logs_dd\log.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write(text)

f.close()
```

When I run this code, everything is running but log size is so small.
I searched and came to know that `"proc.communicate()"`might be the solution.
I tried `'communicate'` but could not solve the issue.
any help pointer pls.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `proc.stdout.read()` with `proc.stdout.readline()` solved it for me. stdout.read() reads everything until EOF - slowing down the speed drastically. A similar question: [Communicate with subprocess without waiting for the subprocess to terminate on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592893/communicate-with-subprocess-without-waiting-for-the-subprocess-to-terminate-on-w)

Answer (score -1):

you can use **adb shell logcat** instead of abd logcat in

proc = subprocess.Popen("adb shell logcat -v time",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

it will give all logs.

i hope it will work.

Comment: Dreamcoder, I have already tried "adb shell logcat", it does not provide full logs.